# Why do I have a null character in my output?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

So, I tried making a program that's supposed to take input for a String from the user and invert each String, somewhat like this for example: stack -> kcats. My program works *almost* fine, except that at the beginning of every string it places 'null' as well!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Q9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string.");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        String[] w = s.split("\\s+");
        String[] r = new String[w.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
            for (int j = w[i].length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                r[i] += w[i].charAt(j);
            }
        }
        String t = String.join(" ", r);
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

It is a simple question, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why I get this output.

```
Enter a string.
stack
nullkcats
```

The first line is my prompt, the second line is my input, and the third line is the output I receive. Could anybody explain why the 'null' appears and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Why are you using String arrays? You are working with a single String.

Comment: I split the string so that I can work with each individual word. It seems like the easiest method to me.

Comment: (It is not a *"null character"*.  It is 4 characters `'n'`, `'u'`, `'l'`, `'l'`.)

Comment: @StephenC You're right! Null character would be nothing there. But those four characters were still pretty annoying.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the default value of an object in Java is Null. Here, the String array index value (i.e r[i]) initially is null. Appending it character result in null with Character output.

- Try initialising default value
- Use Java Editor Debugging feature to see each step's value.

Comment: Right. Each of the r[I] needs to be initialized to the empty String, not null.

Comment: I added a statement r[i] = "" at the beginning of the first loop, and it works fine now. Thanks for the tip!